# Problem when using display none with divs and footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-frontend

Ok, let's say that I have two buttons, a container with two divs and below I have my footer, like this:

```
<button id="bt1">Show all</button>
<button id="bt2">Show curses</button>

<div class="container">
   <div class="one"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

I'm displaying content inside my divs. Div "one" has more height, much more. In order to hide div "two" and don't overlap content, I use opacity:0.

I have two buttons, to show or to hide div "one" or "two" (using jQuery).

But if I only use opacity:0 to hide div "one" when I show div "two", the page leaves a big space empty (due to div "one" has more height than div "two"). As here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HANXg.png)

So I decided to use display:none to hide div "one", in order to don't leave space and just show the necessary space for div "two". But my footer goes up!! And overlaps content with div "two".

Here is the image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxOJh.png)

How can I solve this? Any ideas? I realized that my footer moves because not finding the content of div "one", it goes up. Sorry for my english haha

---

Here I leave you guys an excelent example of what happens to me, you can COPY and run:

HTML:

```js
var cont_all = $('.one');
var bt1 = $('#bt1');
var cont_curses = $('.two');
var bt2 = $('#bt2');

bt2.click(function(){
    cont_all.css('display', 'none');
    cont_curses.css('opacity', '1');
});
bt1.click(function(){
   cont_curses.css('opacity', '0');
   cont_all.css('display', 'flex');
});
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.one, .two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
}

.one {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.chart {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #2096CE;
}

.curse {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #23AD5A;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h2>Problem with divs</h2>
</header>

<button id="bt1">Show all</button>
<button id="bt2">Show curses</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div class="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="curse"></div>
    <div class="curse"></div>
    <div class="curse"></div>
    <div class="curse"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>I'm the footer</p>
</footer>
```

Well it's not the same at all, because it's a big project, but basically is that.

Comment: Can we see your CSS please?

Comment: You have a syntax error where you fail to close the string for `class="two`, which should be fixed as malformed HTML can sometimes cause difficult-to-debug issues.  Would it be possible to create a [mcve] as a snippet to illustrate exactly the issue you are having?  Trying to conceptualize it from the description alone and wondering if the code snippets included are sufficient enough to recreate the issue are a high bar to getting started on this post...

Comment: Yes, both of you are right. I've made the corrections.

Comment: Just apply `bottom:0px;position:fixed` to the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Full answer

check the max-height toggles

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Display None</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <style>
        h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.one, .two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chart {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #2096CE;
}

.curse {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #23AD5A;
}

footer {
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: auto 0;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Problem with divs</h2>
    </header>

    <button id="bt1">Show all</button>
    <button id="bt2">Show curses</button>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
            <div class="chart"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="curse"></div>
            <div class="curse"></div>
            <div class="curse"></div>
            <div class="curse"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>I'm the footer</p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var cont_all = $('.one');
        var bt1 = $('#bt1');
        var cont_curses = $('.two');
        var bt2 = $('#bt2');

        bt2.click(function(){
            cont_all.css('max-height', '0px');
            cont_curses.css('max-height', '100%');
        });
        bt1.click(function(){
           cont_curses.css('max-height', '0px');
           cont_all.css('max-height', '100%');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated my case, I left and excelent example, you just need to copy this html code and css code, could you please help me? :c You will see what happens to me

Comment: I have no words... THANK YOU! It works ;) really thank you

Comment: Well, if alexkarpen answer is what you needed then consider up voting and selecting as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly changed @alexkarpen answer. Instead of max-height you can also use fadeIn() and fadeOut()  jquery function. it looks a little bit cool

```js
var cont_all = $('.one');
var bt1 = $('#bt1');
var cont_curses = $('.two');
var bt2 = $('#bt2');
var cont_project = $('.three');
var bt3 = $('#bt3');

bt2.click(function(){
  cont_all.fadeOut("slow");
  cont_project.fadeOut();
  cont_curses.fadeIn("slow");
});
bt3.click(function(){
  cont_all.fadeOut();
  cont_curses.fadeOut();
  cont_project.fadeIn("slow");
});
bt1.click(function(){
  cont_curses.fadeIn("slow");
  cont_project.fadeIn("slow");
  cont_all.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.one, .two, .three {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.chart {
    background: #2096CE;
}

.curse {
    background: #23AD5A;
}

.project {
  background: pink;
}

footer {
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button id="bt1">Show All</button>
<button id="bt2">Show Curses</button>
<button id="bt3">Show Projects</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="card chart"></div>
    <div class="card chart"></div>
    <div class="card chart"></div>
    <div class="card chart"></div>
    <div class="card chart"></div>
    <div class="card chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="card curse"></div>
    <div class="card curse"></div>
    <div class="card curse"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="card project"></div>
    <div class="card project"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>I'm the footer</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`footer { height: 200px; background: black; color: white;  display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center; position:fixed; bottom: 0px; }`

Comment: I was looking for my footer to stay down, but if I wanted to sticky, your code works, thanks still